# Correlate in load runner with different type of response body

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

While correlation in load runner,
For same request some time response is received in json format and other time response received in XML for eg.

Json response:

`{"VerificationId": "xyzabc123567"}`

XML response be like:

`<VerificationId>abcuwn274637</verificationId>`

Is there any way to correlate it?

Answer (score 1):

Set two correlations for two different variables, such as VerifXML, and VerifJSON.   Your failed one will be empty.   Set the error condition for warning [ "Notfound=warning" ] in the case of a failed correlation.

Assign the non empty collection to a standard loadrunner variable [ lr_save_string(....) ] to continue.